# How do you show party members debuffs on the enemies unit frame in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to be able to see what kind of debuffs are on the enemy from the [select](https://i.gyazo.com/1fa1315aa82093db8ddf1e7bb586bc50.png) window here. How do I enable enemy bebuffs to be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blizzard removed the "show all" option with Legion, but the following command should be what you're looking for:

`/console noBuffDebuffFilterOnTarget 1`

Just type it in chat and you should see all debuffs on your target again.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out after work and toss you the answer if it works!